# Using the parameter names of a function to defining variable names

Tags: r, function, character

I'm new in the world of programming in **R** and I'm trying to understand the logic of such methods.

1. I'm trying to get a solution to following situation:

   ```
   foo <- function(name){
       name <- sqlFetch(connection, name)
   }
   ```

   I want to write a function which is importing tables from a database and names the imported table like its name in the database.
   E.g: 
   If I want to import the table "cars" this table in **R** should also called cars.

   How is it possible to write such a function?
   This should just be a the first part of my function.
2. I have another really simple regarding character as parameters of my function like table names or something.
   As argument I'm using the name enclosed of quotes.
   i.e. "cars" and not cars. Are the quotes included if the function replaces the parameter?

   I'm asking because in the sqlFetch you have to place the table names in quotation marks. 
   So which type of function would be correct, the upper one or the following:

   ```
   foo <- function(name){
       name <- sqlFetch(connection,"name")
   }
   ```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you want to solve? Because as it stands, it’s hard to understand why you wouldn’t simply write `cars = sqlFetch(connection, "cars")`.

Comment: At least I want to write a function which naming and importing a table from a database in R. I can simply write your example but it doesnt work as function with a parameter because of the quotation marks that I used for the parameter. If I´m using the function like this foo("cars") it replaces name by "cars" (with the quotation marks), so I cant define the code as in the upper example

Comment: That’s precisely my question: what functionality do you want to encapsulate in the function? Why have a function at all, rather than just writing the code I wrote in my initial comment? I’m asking because creating variables inside functions is a decidedly bad idea most of the time. The idea of R functions is to be free of side-effects. The only thing it modifies should be the return value.

Comment: So my idea was the following: I ve many tables in Access. I want to read some of them in R with sqlFetch and name them as in Access. After that I want to get them into a R database with the package RSQLite (dbWriteTable). And this should be in one function. The intention behind this idea was that I can just take the Access table name and my function imports this table with the identical name in R and creating this table in the DB of RSQLite. After that I want to merge,join, do some SQL Querys and creating subtables with the imported tables from Access